# get external jsonp and convert coordinates in leafletjs

Tags: leaflet, geojson, json

I need to solve two problems:

1. convert my coordinates from wgs84 to epsg28992
2. use external geojson from an jsonp url

Both problems are as far as I understand not supported by Leaflet itself. So I took a deep dive to found alternative methods.

The content of the jsonp looks like:

```
getmyjson({"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
 { "type":"Feature",
   "properties":{"waarde":72.000000, "code":"002002", "klasse":1, "aant_min_stap":0, "stapgrootte":50.000000, "aant_stappen":4},
   "geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":[129544.434902 , 512753.813614]}
 },
.....
 { "type":"Feature",
   "properties":{"waarde":54.000000, "code":"BDV032", "klasse":1},
   "geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":[117763.299998 , 503647.849492]}
 }
]});
```

The first problem (convert coordinates) I solved by using jquery: [Result](http://waterbug.pythonanywhere.com/static/leaflet1/convertcoors.html)

relevant code:

```
function getmyjson(data) {
      geojsonLayer.addData(data);
 }

 $.getJSON("rdtest.json", function(data) {
    var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        latlngnw=RdWgs84(latlng.lng,latlng.lat)
    return L.circleMarker(latlngnw,{})
      }
    });
    geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
  });
```

The second problem (use external jsonp) I solved by using the plugin leaflet-ajax: [Result](http://waterbug.pythonanywhere.com/static/leaflet1/getjsonp.html)

relevant code:

```
function getmyjson(data) {
      geojsonLayer.addData(data);
      geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
 }

 var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(["wgs84test.jsonp"], {
      dataType:"jsonp",
      callbackParam:"getmyjson",
      });
```

What I want now is to combine both solutions and I have no clue how to do that.

Can anyone help me out ?

---

From ThomasG77 this is the solution to combine 1. and 2. [Result](http://waterbug.pythonanywhere.com/static/leaflet1/solution1.html)

```
function getmyjson(data) {
   geojsonLayer.addData(data);
   geojsonLayer.addTo(mymap);

}

var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(["rdtest.jsonp"], {
    dataType:"jsonp",
    callbackParam:"getmyjson",
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    latlngnw=RdWgs84(latlng.lng,latlng.lat)
    return L.circleMarker(latlngnw,{})
      }

});
```

But I will tweak further to look if I can use Proj4Leaflet to solve it.

---

Alternative for point 1 with use of Proj4Leaflet. [Result](http://waterbug.pythonanywhere.com/static/leaflet1/convertcoors2.html)

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:28992","+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs");
  $.getJSON("rdtest.json", function(data) {

    data.crs={
       "type": "name",
       "properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"}
    };
    L.Proj.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
  });
```

Remaining question now is how I can combine the solutions of point 2 (jsonp) and the above.

Any suggestions ?

---

Final solution. [Result](http://waterbug.pythonanywhere.com/static/leaflet1/solution2.html)

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:28992","+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs");

function getmyjson(data) {
   geojsonLayer.addData(data);
   geojsonLayer.addTo(mymap);
}

var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(["rdtest.jsonp"], {
    dataType:"jsonp",
    callbackParam:"getmyjson",
    pointToLayer: function (data) {
          data.crs={
            "type": "name",
            "properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"}
      };
    return L.Proj.geoJson(data)
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1**

For conversion, other answer already mentioned Proj4Leaflet (it relies on Proj4js) For your particular projection, EPSG 28992, look at [this EPSG.io URL](http://epsg.io/28992)

**Point 2**

For the JSONP, read again [the Leaflet-ajax page](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax).

At the bottom, the doc mentioned below syntax where you can use JSONP with a custom function (and your case, make your coordinates transformation)

```
L.Util.jsonp("http://www.dif.ori/gin").then(function(data){
    doStuff(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tweaked around with that (jsonp) option, but did not succeed (sofar). I will post the tweak I tried later on.

Comment: I tweaked around again I was success full this time. Thanks for putting me on the right track. I tried to higher your score, but looks like I am not allowed yet (not enough reputation ?). I edited my question with the right solution to point 2

Comment: I read in the help 'The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted" '. I would like to mark your answer as accepted but don' see how to do. Maybe I miss something or maybe I don't have enough reputation for that.

Answer (score 0):

With modern proj4Leaflet you should be able to define the projections by using proj4 strings, as demonstrated in https://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/ by (re-)defining EPSG:3006.

You can do the same by doing something like:

```
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:28992',
  '+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.4171,50.3319,465.5524,-0.398957388243134,0.343987817378283,-1.87740163998045,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs',
  {
    resolutions: [
      8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128
    ],
    origin: [0, 0]
  })
```

Comment: great, I missed this. I will dive into this again. Will come back on that.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, no complete answer, but for Leaflet-side reprojection, have a look at [Proj4Leaflet](http://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried something with proj4leaflet already, but I stopped after I got signals it is not supporting epsg28992: https://www.drupal.org/node/2330145   If that is not correct please let me know.

Comment: I am now using my 'own' function RdWgs84 to make the converts, but I realize it is suboptimal. Better alternatives are welcome.